# How to display the auth dialog after the user enters the app?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app and i want to increase the login conversions so i want my users to land on my app's home page to see what i'm offering and then once they clicked they will get the auth dialog. 
How do i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that adding a landing page will increase conversions.  In fact, it may hurt by adding additional clicks to the funnel. However, if you want to try it, here's what you need to do.

Facebook does not prompt for auth until you tell it to.  In order to allow your users to see a landing page before prompting for auth, make sure you do the following:

1) Ensure "Authenticated referrals" are turned **off**.  This can be done in the Developer App under Settings > Auth Dialog

2) If using the JS SDK, make sure you are calling FB.getLoginStatus() so you can redirect users that have already authorized your app to the appropriate page.  (You can also do this server side, using the PHP SDK or equivalent, to avoid the client side redirect).

3) If using the JS SDK, don't call FB.login() until you are ready to prompt for auth.  For instance, you can call this in response to a user clicking a login button on your landing page.  If not using the JS SDK, don't redirect to the auth dialog until after the user clicks your login button.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this carefully:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/

```
void dialog(Context context, String action, DialogListener listener)
```

> Generate a Facebook UI dialog for the request action in the given
>   Android context.
>
> Parameters
>
> context - The Android context in which we will generate this dialog.
>
> action - The type of dialog to call. Currently supported methods are
>   feed and oauth.
>
> listener - Callback interface to notify the application when the
>   dialog has completed.
>
> Return Value
>
> None, the callback interface will be notified when the request has
>   completed.
>
> Note
>
> This method is asynchronous and the callback will be invoked in the
>   original calling thread (not in a background thread).